# Postgres 9.4 select by json array`s element value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.4

There is an 'accounts' table with 'data'::jsonb field filled with:

```
{
    "cars": [{"body": "E-JZA80-ALFQZ", 
         "year": 1999, 
         "brand": "Toyota", 
         "model": "Vista Ardeo"} 
     ], 
    "name": "Gilbert Moore", 
    "phone": "+13222314555"
}
```

I trying something like: 
      `select  * from accounts where data->'cars' @> '{"brand":"Toyota"}'`
But it doesn`t show the record. What a have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query expects the json value in the form:

```
{
    "cars": {"body": "E-JZA80-ALFQZ", 
         "year": 1999, 
         "brand": "Toyota", 
         "model": "Vista Ardeo"} 
     , 
    "name": "Gilbert Moore", 
    "phone": "+13222314555"
}
```

But in the actual data `data->'cars'` is an array, not an object, so the query should be:

```
select a.*
from accounts a
where data->'cars' @> '[{"brand":"Toyota"}]'
```

as operator @> applies to two objects or two arrays.

Comment: I like the cross join solution. But what about operation cost? For example, I have 10 millions of records with 1-3 cars in each.

Comment: I think the query against 10 million rows may take one or few minutes. 
With large amount of data I personally would prefer to convert a json to standardized tables. 
Initially you have to spend extra time to design tables and insert/update functions, but in the long run it brings tangible benefits. In principle I do not use jsonb type if the number of rows may be greater than some 100 000.